# Value can not be null on Role Provider

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, roleprovider

I am beginner at MVC C#. Now I am trying to build a custom authentication with role provider, but when it check for user role its getting an error that "Value can not be null".
Here is my `RoleProvider:`

```
public class MyRoleProvider:RoleProvider
{
    private int _cacheTimeoutInMinute = 20;
    LoginGateway gateway=new LoginGateway();


public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
    {
        if (!HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return null;
        }

        //check cache
        var cacheKey = string.Format("{0}_role", username);
        if (HttpRuntime.Cache[cacheKey] != null)
        {
            return (string[])HttpRuntime.Cache[cacheKey];
        }
        string[] roles

            = gateway.GetUserRole(username).ToArray();
            if (roles.Any())
            {
                HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(cacheKey, roles, null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(_cacheTimeoutInMinute), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);

            }

        return roles;
    }
public override bool IsUserInRole(string username, string roleName)
    {
        var userRoles = GetRolesForUser(username);
            return userRoles.Contains(roleName);   

    }
```

Its always Getting error on `reurn userRoles.Contains(roleName);` (value can not be null(userName)) line. I used debug pointer, it shows gateway never been invoked.I,e:  `string[] roles = gateway.GetUserRole(username).ToArray();` so roles always remain null. 
Although I am not sure that my GetUserRole method on gateway is correct or not: here is my gateway:

```
public string[] GetUserRole(string userName)
    {

        string role = null;
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        string query = "select r.RoleType from RoleTable r join UserRoleTable ur on ur.RoleId=r.Id join UserTable u on u.UserId=ur.UserId where u.UserName='"+userName+"'";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
        connection.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            role = reader["RoleType"].ToString();

        }
        string[] roles = {role};
        reader.Close();
        connection.Close();
        return roles;
    }
```

Is there any problem with my code? and how could I solve this error?

Comment: Does it work if you hard code the return value in `GetUserRole` method? For example, `public string[] GetUserRole(string userName) { return new string[] {"Somerole"}; }`

Comment: it works if I delete or comment out  httpContext and all  code for cache...Is there Anything wrong with cache portion code?? @Win

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it works if I delete or comment out httpContext and all code for
>   cache...Is there Anything wrong with cache portion code?? @Win

I won't worry about hitting database, unless you are developing Enterprise Application in which speed is an issue and every query count. *Original ASP.Net Membership Provider doesn't use Cache at all.*

Besides, ASP.Net Membership Provider is an very old technology - *more than a decade old*. If you are implementing for Enterprise Application, you might want to consider using Claim-Based Authentication.

Here is the cache service if you want to use -

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.Caching;

public class CacheService 
{
    protected ObjectCache Cache => MemoryCache.Default;

    public T Get<T>(string key)
    {
        return (T) Cache[key];
    }

    public void Set(string key, object data, int cacheTime)
    {
        if (data == null)
            return;

        var policy = new CacheItemPolicy();
        policy.AbsoluteExpiration = DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(cacheTime);
        Cache.Add(new CacheItem(key, data), policy);
    }

    public void Remove(string key)
    {
        Cache.Remove(key);
    }
}
```